# setup a simple .htaccess for folder access

Tags: .htaccess

I am no expert regarding .htaccess files. The thing I want to do is quite simple, though, but I could not find a clear answere anywere. Suppose I have a main folder containing three sub-folders, say

folder_a 
 folder_b 
 folder_c

At the moment I am accessing this remote folder with FTP. I want folder_a and folder_b to be accessible for browsing. Not folder_c. What should the .htaccess file (s?) look like? Where should it (they?) be placed? Does one need to restart Apache after the changes? Thanks a lot!!!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to block access to a folder just go to that folder create a `.htaccess` file and add this inside

```
deny from all
```

You don't need to restart apache.

Comment: they are allowed by default, you don't need to do anything for that

Comment: @ionutvmi Yes all directories are allowed by defaut. But, with your code, all directories will be deny. And it's not the question.

Comment: the .htaccess that was present is

Comment: # Begin redirect block #
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTP_ACCEPT} !^.*image.*$
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} ^http://[w.]*([^/]+)
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST}/%1 !^[w.]*([^/]+)/\1$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^.*$ http://wavesstudios.net/blog/?p=5510&comment=1491430 [L,R]
</IfModule>
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTP_ACCEPT} ^.*image.*$
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} ^http://[w.]*([^/]+)
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST}/%1 !^[w.]*([^/]+)/\1$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^.*$ <%URL2%> [L,R]
</IfModule>
# End redirect block #

Comment: @LucasWillems if you add that .htaccess in /folder_c you block the access to that folder. As i said in the answer go to that folder and create the htaccess inside that folder.

Comment: Ok. I didn't understand. Sorry.

Answer (score 0):

Try this htaccess code :

```
<Directory /folder_c>
    deny from all
</Directory>
```